# reCaptcha v3 does not block spam

Tags: recaptcha

I just upgraded to v3 from v2 reCaptcha, it seems v3 does not block most of the spam, i get a lot of spam using it inside wordpress contact form 7. With v2 it was blocking almost every spam email.
What's up with that? Doesn't seem like a good upgrade to me unless i'm missing something? I don't get errors and it looks like it's properly installed.
Anyone of you experience this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing how you implemented everything but most likely you're missing something. Perhaps the main thing you may be missing is that v3 by default spawns in "passive" mode. In which it logs requests and what it "would have done" but doesn't take any action. The idea is to let you gather data to set the blocking threshold to a level that matches your sites reality before engaging the active.blocking modes. You probably have everything in passive mode or you set a way-off threshold

Comment: Where do i set this threshold?

Comment: i mean are you sure about this? it's managed by contact form 7, and i just see it might have to learn what is spam and what is not spam within the next days (google)

Comment: Can't be 100% sure if you don't show code... But you probably aren't validating Google's response or have set a threshold too close to '0.0'. You should read this carefully: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Comment: Hi thanks for your help Javier but i dont see options to set a threshold or anything like that in the reCaptcha admin. I think v3 is only for bigger websites, v2 was working fine for smaller websites, v3 is allowing a LOT of spam for smaller websites, the threshold you talk about is not there in the admin and there is literally no options to choose. Can you please explain where to set the score or threshold, i read the documentation and faq 3 times already, dont see anything, it's like they hide the most useful information and give the obvious information everywhere super simple to read .....

Comment: In many ways, v3 requires the same amount of work by you as v2. In particular, you need to verify the response token using your private key (just as you did in v2). The json you'll get when verifying the response token will contain among other things a score from 0.0 to 1.0 (0.0 being total certainty that the user is a bot and 1.0 being total certainty that the user is human). It's how you handle that response what determines what happens (you could, for example, abort the form for scores below 0.6.. your choice, it's done on your side, not on google's)

Comment: In the link I gave you before, scroll down to "Site Verify Response" which should clear it up for you. Remember it's important to always verify the response token because it's just that, a token.. it doesn't give, by itself, any information on whether the interaction was with a human or a bot. v2 makes it a little less terrible not to verify the token because most of the time a bot doesn't even produce a response from google (so 95%+ of responses are actually passing ones). This is not the case with v3, and has nothing to do with site size :)

Comment: If you could share some code (remember to hide your private key!) to see how you implemented v3 on your site I could give you a hand and point you in the right direction to properly do the token verification

Comment: I think you missed the part where i said it is managed by contact form 7.

Comment: No, I didn't... It may be WordPress+contact form 7, plain PHP or Java. There still needs to be some code posting the request to Google, getting the response token and then validating it for any sort of recaptcha to be effective. If contact form 7 is not doing the work on its own, you need to "hack" the v3 implementation into it otherwise it won't work :)

Comment: Facing the same issue

Comment: I'm confused about this "passive" mode. When I implemented the code, I followed the steps under "[Automatically bind the challenge to a button](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3)" but my [contact](http://www.collybird.com/contact) form sends me spam as if reCAPTCHA isn't doing anything at all. Any help would be appreciated.